# Const or static property on record type in C#

Tags: c#

I have a record type

```
record Test(int Magic);
```

and I want to define some constant value that is not required to be configurable e.g. so I can access it like this

```
Test.MyMagicConst
```

In F# I can use modules to define a constant under the same name as a record type.

Is that possible to achieve something similar in C# and records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can add additional properties inside the definition of the record:

```
public record Test(int Magic)
{
    public const int MyMagicConst = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A few options, a const field, or a static readonly field, or a static property

1. **a const field** for simple types

   ```
   public record Test(int Magic)
   {
       public const int MyMagicConst = 100;
   }
   ```
2. **static readonly field** for more complex types

   ```
   public record Test(int Magic)
   {
       public static readonly int MyMagicConst = 100;
   }
   ```
3. **static calculated property** for when you need some calculations done first

   ```
   public record Test(int Magic)
   {
       public static int MyMagicConst {get => IsHardCore ? 10 :100; }
   }
   ```
4. **static readonly property** for when you need to have a property instead of a field

   ```
   public record Test(int Magic)
   {
       public static int MyMagicConst { get; } = 100;
   }
   ```